# Both Flash and Alternate Displaying In Firefox, Nothing but Errors in IE (sIFR)

Tags: sifr

I've just installed and setup sIFR on my Magento store. An example page can be seen here:

http://www.mint-creative.co.uk/shop

And you can see it loads the heading brilliantly, but still displays the alternate text-only headline. I've quadruple checked the .css files and everything's loading ok I think. Also, in IE it doesn't display at all and every .css and .js file has an error according to the error log in IE8.

Any help on this would be great as it's an urgent project!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with IE8.  The best thing to do is put this in your header

< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

(I had to add a space after < to get it to show up for some reason so make sure you delete that space)

It'll fix your problem.

I'd also try Cufon or Font-face over sIFR.

Comment: Thanks for that answer mate.

Any chance of anyone pointing out the problem with sIFR before I start swapping about?

Answer (score 0):

There's a parse error in the CSS files. Try validating them and see what comes up.